# Angularjs route: prevent user to manually get json data

Tags: angularjs, laravel

In my angularjs app I have route `/#/tasks`, which fetch tasks from `/tasks` url. If user manually goes to `/tasks` url, he gets json data. Should I prevent show json data to user? What is the best practice? For example, in backend I can check if request is ajax or not. If not - redirect to base url. Backend - `laravel 5`.

Answer (score 1):

From the title of the post having the keywords '**prevent user**', it seems that you need some sort of logic to define access privileges for a particular user.

You could stick to resolving the authorization logic ***before*** a user ever accesses a route.
For this, you can take advantage of the [`$routeProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)'s `resolve` property of the `.when()` method.

According to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider), the `resolve` property is ...

> An optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the controller. If any of these dependencies are promises, the router will wait for them all to be resolved or one to be rejected before the controller is instantiated.
>
> *If all the promises are resolved successfully, the values of the resolved promises are injected and $routeChangeSuccess event is fired. If any of the promises are rejected the $routeChangeError event is fired.*

The resolve takes in functions (as injectable dependencies) each of which may return a *promise*, and if any of the promises get rejected, as quoted, an error is thrown and literally, neither the route nor the view is loaded.

For the authorization logic to work, you'll need to perform some API call to some backend function/service which either resolves that the user is permitted for the route, or rejects his/her request.

```
.when('/tasks', {
resolve: {
    authorize: function(authService){
            //some api call to get either acceptance (e.g. status code 200) or rejection (status code 500) for the user being authorized
            return authService.authorize();
        }
    },
    controller: function(){
        //route controller logic
    }
})
```

Alternatively, if you'd also want to perform something on failure of the promise, you could do so by simply chaining the promise with a `catch()` handler and throw an error to forcefully reject the promise that is returned from the `catch()` itself.

```
.when('/tasks', {
resolve: {
    authorize: function($location, authService){
        //some api call to get either acceptance or rejection for the user being 
        return authService.authorize()
             .then(function(){
                //some logic on success of the promise
             })
             .catch(function(){
                $location.path('/auth/login/');
                throw 'Authorization error';
             });
        }
    },
    controller: function(){
        //route controller logic
    }
})
```